# NN: AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, keras, classification

I try to use Keras for a simple binary classification. For this I have created a simple neural network.

```
#hyperparameters
hidden_units=100
learning_rate=0.01
hidden_layer_act='tanh'
output_layer_act='sigmoid'
no_epochs=100

#model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(hidden_units, input_dim=len(X_train.columns), activation=hidden_layer_act))
model.add(Dense(hidden_units, activation=hidden_layer_act))
model.add(Dense(1, activation=output_layer_act))
#model.summary()
sgd=optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', 
                                   mode='max', # don't minimize the accuracy!
                                   patience=10,
                                   restore_best_weights=True)
model = model.fit(X_train,
                  y_train, 
                  epochs=no_epochs,
                  callbacks=[es],
                  batch_size=5, 
                  verbose=1,
                  shuffle=True)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I tried available solution here already. But it is not working. I do not understand what I am doing wrong here. Please guide me.

Comment: model = model.fit This is not valid code, where did you get it? just call model.fit without assigning it to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.fit` returns a *[history object](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/History)*, with information about the training. It **does not return the model**.
So `model = model.fit()` will **overwrite the variable** and will not point to your actual model anymore, thus `.predict` will not work.

Do:

```py
history = model.fit(X_train,
                  y_train, 
                  epochs=no_epochs,
                  callbacks=[es],
                  batch_size=5, 
                  verbose=1,
                  shuffle=True)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

or just write `model.fit` without assigning it if you are not interested in the variable