# TypeError: 'History' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, visualization

I am trying to implement saliency_map. I am using DenseNet121 and I fit the model.
cose snippet:

```
for train_index, val_index in skf.split(X_train, y_train):
    X_train_fold, X_val_fold = X_train[train_index], X_train[val_index]
    y_train_fold, y_val_fold = y_train[train_index], y_train[val_index]
    i = i+1;
    print("Fold:",i)
    DenseNet121 = model.fit(datagen.flow(X_train_fold, y_train_fold, batch_size=32), epochs=10, verbose=1,validation_data=(X_val_fold,y_val_fold) ,callbacks=[ es_callback])
```

code snippet of saliency_map:

```
# Function to generate saliency maps
def generate_saliency_map(model, X, y):
    # Convert numpy arrays to TensorFlow tensors
    X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
    y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y)
    X = tf.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(X)
        output_tensor = model(X)
        output_class = tf.math.argmax(output_tensor, axis=-1)
        one_hot = tf.one_hot(output_class, depth=4)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(output_tensor * one_hot, axis=-1)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, X)
    saliency_map = tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(grads), axis=-1)
    return saliency_map
# Generate saliency maps for a few test images
for i in range(5):
    # print(X_test[i].shape)
    saliency_map = generate_saliency_map(DenseNet121, X_test[i], y_test[i])
    plt.imshow(saliency_map, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

Error: `TypeError: 'History' object is not callable`

I am attaching a picture for better understanding of the error.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NN: AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75225720/nn-attributeerror-history-object-has-no-attribute-predict)

Comment: @Daraan I'm afraid It's not. `output_tensor = model(X)` this line is causing the error

Comment: Model.fit does not return a model, so that line of code does not make any sense

Comment: Now I understand the problem! Thank you so much @Dr.Snoopy .  But can you please tell me how to solve this as I am fitting the model in folds?

Comment: Remove the `DenseNet121 =` part, just go with model.fit, then the training will happen in folds.

Comment: the training part is not causing the error, but the saliency_map is. The problem is with this line `output_tensor = model(X)`

Comment: pass model into saliency_map, not DenseNet121

Answer (score 0):

This line overwrite your previous Keras model with an History object.

```
DenseNet121 = model.fit(datagen.flow(X_train_fold, y_train_fold, batch_size=32), epochs=10, verbose=1,validation_data=(X_val_fold,y_val_fold) ,callbacks=[ es_callback])
```

If you want to store the history of the training you can declare a new variable

```
history = model.fit(datagen.flow(X_train_fold, y_train_fold, batch_size=32), epochs=10, verbose=1,validation_data=(X_val_fold,y_val_fold) ,callbacks=[es_callback])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `model` as argument instead of `DenseNet121` in `generate_saliency_map` as `DenseNet121` holds the history object not the model. Something like this,

```py
# Generate saliency maps for a few test images
for i in range(5):
    # print(X_test[i].shape)
    saliency_map = generate_saliency_map(model, X_test[i], y_test[i])
    plt.imshow(saliency_map, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```